# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus Continuity at Right-end Point

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I'm trying to prove the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus when $f : [a,b] \to \Bbb{R}$ is continuous at $b$. I've already handled the case of continuity at $a$, but continuity at the right endpoint is giving me trouble. Here is an attempt:

> If $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $x \in (b-\delta,b)$ implies $|f(x)-f(b)| < \epsilon$. If $t \in (0,\delta)$, then
>
> $$|\frac{F(b-t)-F(b)}{t}-f(b)|= \frac{1}{t}|\int_{a}^{b-t}f(x)dx - \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx - tf(b)|$$
>
> $$= \frac{1}{t} |\int_{a}^{b-t}f(x)dx - \int_{a}^{b-t}f(x)dx - \int_{b-t}^bf(x)dx -tf(b)|$$
>
> $$= \frac{1}{t}|- \int_{b-t}^bf(x)dx -tf(b)|$$

Unfortunately, this isn't obviously less than/equal to $\frac{1}{t} \int_{b}^{b-t}|f(x)-f(b)|dx$, which is what I want, since at that point I could invoke $f$'s left-handed continuity at $b$. My textbook said that the two cases are very similar, but I don't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a sign error in

> $$|\frac{F(b-t)-F(b)}{\color{red} t}-f(b)|= \frac{1}{t}|\int_{a}^{b-t}f(x)dx - \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx - tf(b)|$$

It should be

$$|\frac{F(b-t)-F(b)}{\color{red}{-t}}-f(b)|= \frac{1}{t}|\int_{a}^{b-t}f(x)dx - \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx + tf(b)|.$$

This should give

$$\frac{1}{t}|- \int_{b-t}^bf(x)dx +tf(b)|=\frac{1}{t}|-\int_{b-t}^bf(x)dx +\int_{b-t}^bf(b)dx| \le \frac1t\int_{b-t}^b |f(x)-f(b)| dx\le\epsilon.$$